# JSONPath issu returning value using a filter

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I have the following json, for which I'm having trouble selecting one of the values using a filter.  Specifically, I want to return "POS_Undeclared"

```
{"wd:Program_of_Study_Reference": {
                                                    "wd:ID": [
                                                        {
                                                            "@wd:type": "WID",
                                                            "$": "123456789abcde"
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "@wd:type": "Program_of_Study_ID",
                                                            "$": "POS_Undeclared"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
}
```

This jsonpath **`$.wd:Program_of_Study_Reference.wd:ID[1].$`**   gives me what I need, but I cannot count on the ordering to be consistent or even exist, hence cannot use [1] .

I cannot seem to get a filter like @wd:type == Program_of_Study_ID to work. I'm guessing it is the @ and/or the : goofing up my syntax.

How can I filter to get the value POS_Undeclared ?

Comment: I meant to write, I'm guessing it is the $, the @ or the : character goofing up my syntax.

Comment: I think it is the $, as I'm able to get this working:
$.wd:Program_of_Study_Reference.wd:ID.[?(@['@wd:type'] == "Program_of_Study_ID")]

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$.wd:Program_of_Study_Reference.*[?(@['@wd:type'] == "Program_of_Study_ID")].$
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jack.   I would have thought that would work, but what JSONPath evaluator brings back is this:[
  {
    "@wd:type": "Program_of_Study_ID",
    "$": "POS_Undeclared"
  }
]

Comment: @ACesario I [tested it here](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/), under the Jayway tab.